# Bloco de código congelando e não lança exception

Tags: c#

Estou usando a biblioteca twain para scanner,e a aplicação lista alguns dispositivos que ao selecionar não funciona,então eu debuguei e vi que não lança a exception que tratei, e sim congela nesse código

```
 public void Acquire()
    {
        TwRC rc;
        CloseSrc();
        if (appid.Id == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Init(hwnd);
            if (appid.Id == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;
        }
        try
        {
            //CONGELA NESSE BLOCO ABAIXO E NÂO LANÇA EXCEPTION
            rc = DSMident(appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Identity, TwMSG.OpenDS, srcds);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ScannerException("Não foi possivel digitalizar, verifique o driver selecionado!");
        }
        TwCapability cap = new TwCapability(TwCap.XferCount, 1);
        rc = DScap(appid, srcds, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Capability, TwMSG.Set, cap);
        if (rc != TwRC.Success)
        {
            CloseSrc();
            throw new ScannerErroDigitalizarException("Erro ao carregar driver selecionado. Verifique se o driver pertence a um Scanner.");
        }

        TwUserInterface guif = new TwUserInterface();
        guif.ShowUI = 1;
        guif.ModalUI = 1;
        guif.ParentHand = hwnd;
        rc = DSuserif(appid, srcds, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.UserInterface, TwMSG.EnableDS, guif);
        if (rc != TwRC.Success)
        {
            CloseSrc();
            throw new ScannerErroDigitalizarException("Erro ao carregar driver selecionado. Verifique se o driver pertence a um Scanner.");
        }
    }
```

como tratar o mesmo?

Referência: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner

Comment: Precisa colocar mais código para dar mais contexto, dizer qual exceção, indicar documentação da biblioteca.

Comment: Editado @bigown ...

Comment: @WarLock, estou equivocado ou você primeiro tenta importar a imagem antes de carregar os drivers?

Observei que depois do try...catch tem as instruções do driver e no final o erro "Erro .... ", será que não está invertido?

Comment: @WarLock o comando funcionou?

Answer (score 4):

Pode ser que o código esteja travando em alguma exceção interna da biblioteca, porém não mostra o erro devido a essa exceção ser tratada pela própria biblioteca ou devido a ela ficar esperando por alguma resposta de um componente externo (o scanner, por exemplo).

Para fazer com que o Visual Studio pare nessas exceções internas, faça o seguinte:

1. Enquanto estiver depurando a aplicação, abra a janela **Exceptions** por meio do menu **Debug -> Exceptions...** ou atralho de teclado **CTRL + D + E**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Na janela Exceptions, marque algumas ou todas as checkboxes na coluna **Thrown**.
3. Simule sua funcionalidade novamente. Se o motivo do congelamento for realmente uma exceção interna, o Visual Studio irá parar em cada uma dessas exceções dando a você uma oportunidade de obter mais informações sobre o erro.

Sugiro que você analise a mensagem e demais detalhes de cada uma dessas exceções internas que vierem a ocorrer no bloco de código que está congelando. Uma delas dará a você a direção correta para solucionar o problema real que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Obrigado por tentar me ajudar, eu fiz isso e apareceu AccessViolationException, erro ao tentar salvar memoria não permitida.É uma dll que não tenho acesso ao código, o que quero fazer é jogar a mensagem para o usuario dizendo que não foi possivel... ainda ta congelando e fechando a aplicação.

Comment: Agora sim descobrimos o erro! Pesquisei aqui e parece haver uma solução. Por favor, instale esse hotfix https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971030 na máquina na qual está rodando a aplicação e tente novamente. Ele trata essa questão de tentativa de acesso a memória não permitida.

Comment: Por favor, desculpe a ignorancia mas não achei o link do download, poderia me passar aqui?

Comment: Tranquilo. Eu coloquei no comentário anterior. É esse link => https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971030

Comment: Eu quis dizer q não achei o link de download dentro desse link que você me passou

Comment: Ah sim. Verdade, olhei a página realmente não tem o link do download. O que ela diz é que esse hotfix foi substituído por outro, o qual resolve mais alguns problemas além desse do acesso à memória protegida. O link desse novo hotfix é https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981574. Porém, **a página diz que é necessário entrar em contato direto com o suporte da microsoft para obter o hotfix**, por meio da página http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ws=support. Parece que não vai ser tão simples assim. Enquanto não surgir outra resposta eu vou tentar obter esse hotfix e se conseguir te aviso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25881/discussion-between-ulysses-alves-and-war-lock).

Comment: Ok, fico no aguardo, vou procurar tambem obrigado.

Comment: @WarLock  encontrei um fórum no qual disseram que resolveram esse problema executando o comando **netsh winsock reset**. Será que esse comando também não daria certo pra esse caso?

Comment: @WarLock, estou equivocado ou você primeiro tenta importar a imagem antes de carregar os drivers?

Observei que depois do try...catch tem as instruções do driver e no final o erro "Erro .... ", será que não está invertido?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves  onde executo esse comando?

Comment: @WarLock Na linha de comandos do Windows. Primeiro abra o prompt de comandos do Windows pelo menu **Iniciar -> Executar -> cmd**. Aí dentro da janela da linha de comandos você digita o comando **netsh winsock reset** e pressiona a tecla ENTER do teclado. É aconselhável que você abra a linha de comandos como administrador. Para isso, no menu iniciar, digite cmd e quando aparecer o ícone do programa clique nele com o botão direito e clique em "Executar como administrador". Neste artigo está mais detalhado http://pt.m.wikihow.com/Abrir-o-Prompt-de-Comando-no-Windows